# 中国語と日本語が混在しているcsv(shift jis win)をphpで読み込み方法について

Tags: php, csv, shift-jis, locale

こんにちは。
中国語と日本語が混在しているshift jis winのcsvをphpで以下のようにして読み込もうとしているのですが、中国語だけ文字化けしてしまうのですが、どのようにすればutf-8で読み込めるのでしょうか。

[FYI] csv自体はプロジェクトの都合によりshift jis winで保存しなければいけないので、shift jis win->utf-8の変換をしたい感じとなります。

■ csv

```
言葉, 中国語訳
こんにちは, 您好
ありがとう, 谢谢啦
```

■ csvの16進ダンプ

```
$ hexdump -x ./test.csv
0000000    be8c    7497    922c    8d86    8c91    96ea    0af3    b182
0000010    f182    c982    bf82    cd82    3f2c    448d    820a    82a0
0000020    82e8    82aa    82c6    2ca4    3f3f    0a3f
000002c
```

```
$ xxd ./test.csv
00000000: 8cbe 9774 2c92 868d 918c ea96 f30a 82b1  ...t,...........
00000010: 82f1 82c9 82bf 82cd 2c3f 8d44 0a82 a082  ........,?.D....
00000020: e882 aa82 c682 a42c 3f3f 3f0a            .......,???.
```

■ ソース

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen($argv[1], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle))) {
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            mb_convert_variables('utf-8','sjis-win', $value);
            echo "${value},";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

■ 出力

```
言葉,中国語訳,
こんにちは,?好,
ありがとう,???,
```

Comment: ちなみにその前の疑問として、元々の.csvファイルが単純なテキストデータとしては表示されないように思えるのですが、.csvファイルの入力や確認・表示はどうやっているのでしょうか？

Comment: SJISでは(SJIS-winでも)、文字化けしている位置にある「您」「谢」「啦」などのJISに定義されていない文字を扱うことはできません。従って、元のCSVファイルにそれらが含まれているのであれば、それはSJISではない、と言うことになります。CSVファイルの16進ダンプを示してもらえないでしょうか。

Comment: @kunif 
csvの読み込み方法は以下のようにして引数でcsvファイルのパスを渡しています。   

`php sample.php ./test.csv`
csvの中身の確認はmacの「LibreOffice Vanilla」というソフトでshift jisで開いて確認しています。

Comment: @kunif 
すみません、もう1度csvファイル開き直したら、shift_jisで文字化けしてました。やはり@OOPer さんが言うようにJISに定義されてないものは読めないようですね。。。。

Comment: @user3321541 「LibreOffice Vanilla」で表示している時は問題無いのなら、そのツールでUTF-8に変換してセーブすれば良いのでは？

Comment: 各国漢字混在のデータを一つのCSVにしたいのであれば、現実的にはCSVそのものをUTF-8で出力するしかないでしょうね。何かその辺ができない事情があるのであれば、そこら辺も質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: 失礼しました、16進ダンプ記載して質問編集しなおしておきました。
試しにutf8でcsv保存してみたら正常に出力できるようになりました！
プロジェクトの都合でshift_jisで保存するようになっているのですが、ちょっとそこらへんどうにかできないか整理してみます。mm

Comment: 了解しました。(中国語漢字をファイルに含めたいのであればShift_JISはダメですね。「プロジェクトの都合」の方を変えてもらわないといけないでしょう。) これで、所望の動作はさせられそうでしょうか? ちなみに`hexdump -C test.csv`のように`-C`オプションを付けると、ダンプ表示が1バイト単位になりますよ。

Comment: @OOPer 
ありがとうございます！とりあえず、csv保存の文字コードさえどうにかできればなんとかなりそうです。お！-Cの方が見やすいですね！

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

CSVにBOMをつけたらどうですか？

#### CSV出力コード

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'wb');

$list = [
    ['言葉', '中国語訳'],
    ['こんにちは', '您好'],
    ['ありがとう', '谢谢啦'],
];

// Prepend BOM
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

#### CSV入力コード

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
$bom = chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF);

if ($fp !== FALSE) {
    $encoding = 'UTF-8';
    if (fgets($fp, 4) !== $bom) {
        rewind($fp);
        $encoding = 'SJIS-WIN';
    }

    while (($data = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE) {
        foreach ($data as $value) {
            mb_convert_variables('UTF-8', $encoding, $value);
            echo "${value},";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

---

### やや長い説明

Shift_JIS（及びMSによる拡張を含むCP932）には中国語の「您」「谢」「啦」といった漢字が含まれていません。そのため、少なくともこれらの文字を含むShift_JISのCSVファイルというものは存在しません。

提示されているCSVは16進ダンプを見る限り、Shift_JISとして表現できない文字はすべてCSVの段階でリテラルの `? (3f)` に変換されており、もとの中国語の情報はすでに失われています。ですので、CSVへの保存の仕方を考え直す必要があるでしょう。

CSVを保存する必要があり、しかもそれがShift_JIS縛りになっているのは、大半が「Excelで保存されているCSVを表示/確認したい」という要望の為だと思います。ExcelはBOMが付与されている場合に限りUTF-8のCSVファイルを正しく読むことができます。

上のコードはそのようなExcelのクセをPHPで真似たものです。入力コードをBOM付きUTF-8に対応させ、互換性のため既存のShift_JISのCSVを読めるようにしておきます。